# why can not use strcpy to put a string, which is get from a result of strtok, into a defined string

Tags: c

I'm trying to use `strtok` to get the string from a text, and then put it into a string by `strcpy`, which is predefined. But it seems the code doesn't work. Where is the bug?

```
int main(void) {

  char c[20][40];
  char s[]="C (pronounced like the letter C) is a general-purpose computer       programming language.";
  char *delim=" ; ( ) . , \n";
  char *p;

  p=strtok(s, delim);

  while (p!=NULL){

    p=strtok(NULL, delim);
    strcpy(c[0],p);

    printf("%s\n", c[0]);

  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" sigh. And would a bit of formatting hurt?

Comment: `But it seems the code doesn't work` can you please share why'd you think that?

Comment: You are missing a few `#include`s: compiler thinks function work differently than what they really do. Also **turn on your compiler warnings** and heed them!

Comment: compile is ok, but when you run it, a window pop up and say "xx.exe is stop running"

Comment: #include <string.h> I already put in the code, but didn't show up here

Comment: I see nothing in your question to indicate what you perceive as a bug.  "Why doesn't my code work" is a bit too general.

Comment: no warning and no error, the code stop when run it. no any sign. if I take of strcpy(c[0],p);  the code works. so I think something wrong with the strcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem:

```
p=strtok(s, delim);

while (p!=NULL){
    p=strtok(NULL, delim);
```

If the first `strtok` succeeds then you ignore the result and go on to call `strtok` again.

Then you write `strcpy(c[0],p);` without checking if `p` is `NULL`.

The proper order of operations should be:

- call strtok
- check it wasn't NULL
- do the copying
- do the printing

It would be nice to have all of this in one loop, however `strtok` requires different arguments for its first call so we have no choice but to hoist one call out of the loop:

```
p = strtok(s, delim);

while ( p != NULL )
{
    strcpy(c[0], p);

    printf("%s\n", c[0]);

    p = strtok(NULL, delim);
 }
```

Also, you are saving all the strings into `c[0]` (so later ones overwrite earlier ones). You probably intend to use an incrementing loop counter so that you save all of the tokens into different rows of `c`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the correct #includes, reorder the following lines:

```
strcpy(c[0],p);
printf("%s\n", c[0]);
p=strtok(NULL, delim);
```

You advance past the end of the string and `p` becomes NULL and still try to `strcpy` it.

Answer (score -1):

```
return 1; // usualy indicates some error
```

Try replacing that with the usual indicator for "OK":

```
return 0; // return EXIT_SUCCESS; // <stdlib.h> defines EXIT_SUCCESS as 0
```

Comment: This is an issue although certainly not the main problem